# comment_form - show all fields when logged in

Tags: wp-admin, login, comment-form

I'm using the http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form in my comments. If logged in I'm seeing only the textarea for my comment, **not the fields for e-mail and name.**

**Question**

Is it possible to make them visible even when logged in? Why would I want to do that? I'm designing themes and it would be easier for me as a designer to see what visitors see.

Comment: Hey, did you figure out how to display those fields when logged in? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `'comment_form_logged_in'` and return the missing fields.

But there is a much easier way: Open a tab in private browsing modus and visit the same page.

Comment: I do essentially the same thing. I just use a separate browser (develop in Chrome, view as not-logged-in using Firefox).