# Force to show all fields in comment forms to the logged-in users

Tags: comments, comment-form

I want to force to show all fields (if possible these can pre-filled with user own e-mail and name data) to the logged-in users. So I found [a reply](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52811/1506) on Wordpress Development/SE Community but I don't know how to figure it out. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can paste the code below in your theme functions.php file, it should generate almost the same comment form for logged in and logged out users

```
add_filter( "comment_form_fields", function( $comment_fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Get an array of field names, excluding the textarea
        $comment_field_keys = array_diff( array_keys( $comment_fields ), array( 'comment' ) );

        // Get the first and the last field name, excluding the textarea
        $first_field = reset( $comment_field_keys );
        $last_field  = end( $comment_field_keys );

        foreach ( $comment_fields as $name => $field ) {
            if ( 'comment' === $name ) {
                echo apply_filters( 'comment_form_field_comment', $field );
                //echo $args['comment_notes_after'];
            } else {
                if ( $first_field === $name ) {
                    do_action( 'comment_form_before_fields' );
                }
                echo apply_filters( "comment_form_field_{$name}", $field ) . "\n";

                if ( $last_field === $name ) {
                    do_action( 'comment_form_after_fields' );
                }
            }
        }
        return array();
    }
    return $comment_fields;
}, 2000 );
```

Note that i have not checked if the entered data in the form will be used when saving the comment you should check it (as WordPress might force use the user details saved in the profile).

Comment: It's worked! Thank you for the answer. 